# Micromax A250 throws java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException before playing Video in VideoView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

Hi everyone today i am facing an Unexpected crash in my android app code works fine with all devices except in Micromax A250. Code i am using to play video from raw folder looks like this :

```
if (mediaControls == null) {
        mediaControls = new MediaController(AndroidVideoViewExample.this);
    }
myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
 try {
        myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.samplevideo);
        Log.d("URI", uri.toString());
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                myVideoView.start();

        }
    });
```

logcat traces are :

> 12-28 15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-28     15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=11; regionStart=0;
>   regionLength=-1 12-28 15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):  at
>   java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464) 12-28 15:08:30.547:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21939):  at
>   android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:407) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:727) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:606) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:692)
>   12-28 15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
>   12-28 15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
>   12-28 15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
>   12-28 15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
>   12-28 15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 12-28 15:08:30.547:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21939):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-28 15:08:30.547:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21939):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   12-28 15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 12-28
>   15:08:30.547: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

and log trace for URI are :

> URI android.resource://com.samplePlayVideo/2130968576

I don't know why it is happening...help is Appreciated ! thanks in advance.

Comment: try print your url:Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.samplevideo)

Comment: @S-MILE-S getting uri while debug but error is coming

Comment: All Micromax phones face this issue, it is a vendor specific conflict. This includes the Micromax A117 and others. One possible hacky solution would be to detect for Micromax as a manufacturer and if so, instead of using VideoView, use a TextureView for your videos. This may stop the crashes. Although personally, I think the best course of action is to add that device to your ban list. I rather doubt too many uses actually use that device, relative to all other Android users.

Answer (score 0):

Its a issue in some Micromax devices, `videoview` is not supported so i found a solution rather than using `videoview` i am using `SurfaceView` and it is working in all devices.